# sanitize issue with ampersand(&) in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sanitize

I used sanitize() method instead of html_safe(), to avoid brakeman warning. But I got some issues while using Ampersand symbol in code.

Eg:

```
sanitize("A & B")
```

I am getting output like `A &amp; B`

But I need output like `A & B`
Any ideas ?

Comment: Hm, works for me `<%= sanitize("A & B") %>` gives me `A & B`

Comment: I used this code inside js.erb. Please try in js.erb file

Comment: Maybe I'm doing smth wrong, but `$(".sanitize-output").html("<%= escape_javascript(sanitize("A & B"))%>");` gives me `A & B`